# `git clean` from other working directory

Tags: git

Some git commands take a `--git-dir` argument, but `git clean` doesn't seem to do so.

How can I do what `cd someDir && git clean -abcd` would have done, without changing working directory?

Comment: Run it in a subshell? (e.g. `(cd someDir && git clean -abcd)`)?

Comment: `--git-dir` is an option to the `git` command itself, not any particular subcommand. It specifies which repository to apply the command to (the default is to use whichever repo is found in the current directory or an ancestor thereof.)

Answer (score 3):

`--git-dir` is an option of `git`, not `git-clean`.

```
git --git-dir someDir/.git clean -abcd
```

Comment: Ok, I've cleaned my working directory twice now using `git --git-dir=a/b/.git clean -abcd`; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably actually want `git --work-tree=someDir clean -abcd`, since it's the working directory you want to specify, not the `.git` dir. But, of course, you'll need a recent-enough `git`; although the fact that you already have separate work trees tends to indicate you do already...